# How to scale a subset of data with respect to the entire dataset

Tags: scikit-learn, time-series, predictive-modeling, feature-scaling, theory

I am developing a financial time-series prediction model using sklearn using `StandardScaler` for scaling purposes. I train a model, and then use the model regularly on data as it comes in. The training must be done in batches due to the large data size. Right now, I am scaling each batch using a different scaler for training each batch, and for each test/real data batch.

My concern is that removing the mean from a subset of the data removes a good deal of information - the scaled data for an asset trading at at \$1500 is not clearly distinguishable from the data for a penny stock.

I'm wondering whether it is possible to - and whether I should - continually re-fit the same scaler used in training, so that data is scaled to remove the mean *with respect to the entire dataset* (ie. train + the actual data being evaluated), and whether this is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find some consensus in various stack* sites - the answer is apparently to scale test data with respect to the train data - ie. `(testData - mean(trainData)) / sd(trainData)`, or with sklearn `scaler.fit(train_data); scaler.transform(test_data)`.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174823/how-to-apply-standardization-normalization-to-train-and-testset-if-prediction-i